# Wordpress - Why won't the_title filter change the post title?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

EDIT: Solved the problem

Heres the code:

```
function my_function($content){
    return str_replace('Microsoft', 'Apple', $content);
}

add_filter('the_content', 'my_function');
add_filter( 'the_title', 'my_function');
```

The content part works, all the Microsoft words in the posts content get changed to Apple. The post title doesn't change though. I gave the post the title: "MicrosoftMy Microsoft Page Microsoft Microsoft" but none of the Microsoft words get replaced.

SOLUTION:

In my plugin PHP file, I have a main function:

```
function create_main_page() {
    add_filter('the_content', 'my_function' );
    add_filter( 'the_title', 'my_function' );
    ...
}
```

and I call this function by entering  into the wordpress HTML editor (I had to install the PHP Execution plugin to enable me to enter PHP into the HTML editor). For some reason when I call the add_filter functions from within this create_main_page function, things get messed up because it can't interact with the header. When I call the add_filter functions from the page itself, it works.

Comment: How is your title displayed? If it's displayed in the sort of `echo $post->post_title;` - it will never change with the filter. This is a common mistake(sometimes it might be intended) when developing WordPress themes - displaying the title(or any other part actually) of a post without filtering it. If that's the case, simply change this to `echo get_the_title( $post->ID );` or `echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $post->post_title );`

Answer (score 0):

Try using separate method for content and title

```
function my_function_content($content){
    return str_replace('Microsoft', 'Apple', $content);
}


function my_function_title($title){
    return str_replace('Microsoft', 'Apple', $title);
}


add_filter('the_content', 'my_function_content');
add_filter( 'the_title', 'my_function_title');
```

Comment: I figured out how to fix it, I'll post the code for other people who happen to run into this problem.